# Implementing multiple generic Interfaces in java

Tags: java, generics

I've need an interface that assures me a certain method, including specific signature, is available. So far his is what I have:

```
public interface Mappable<M> {
    M mapTo(M mappableEntity);
}
```

The problem arises when a class should be mappable to multiple other entities. The ideal case would be this (not java):

```
public class Something implements Mappable<A>, Mappable<B> {
    public A mapTo(A someObject) {...}
    public B mapTo(B someOtherObject) {...}
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this remaining as "generic" as possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is, of course, not something you can do due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime, you have two methods `public Object mapTo(Object)`, which obviously cannot coexist.

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is simply beyond Java's type system.

Assuming your generic type is always a first class type, and not itself generic, you could achieve similar outward-facing behaviour by having the method `mapTo(Object, Class)`, which would allow you to do runtime inspection of the given class and decide which behaviour to use. Obviously this is pretty inelegant--and will require manual casting of the return value--but I think it's the best you can do. If your generic types are themselves generic, then their generic parameters will be erased too and their Classes will be equal, so this method won't work.

However, I would point towards @Joachim's answer as well, this may be a case where you can split the behaviour out into separated components and sidestep the whole issue.

Answer (score 6):

As you saw, you can't implement the same interface twice with different type parameters (because of erasure: at runtime they are the same interfaces).

Also, this approach violates the single responsibility principle: your class should focus on being a `Something` (whatever that means) and should not do the mapping to `A` or `B` *in addition* that task.

It sounds like you really should have a `Mapper<Something,A>` and a `Mapper<Something,B>`. This way each class has a single clearly-defined responsibility *and* you don't run into the problem of implementing the same interface twice.

Comment: Well, the idea is to let the class be responsible for "transforming" its contents to other objects. Then there's a dispatcher that handle them in a Class agnostic manner, therefore the generics requirement. I'll think a bit about extracting the logic, though that actually means I'm splitting the class in two, but they remain tightly coupled (access to field should be granted, modifying one most of the times imply modifying the other, etc)

Comment: @estani: yes, they are somewhat tightly coupled, but they have distinct responsibilities. Also think about this: when you introduce a new class `C` and you want `Something` to be mappable to that, then you'd need to modify `Something`, which is too much coupling. Just adding a new `SoemthingToCMapper` is less intrusive.

Comment: +1 to this - generally speaking you should favour composition over inheritance if you're trying to achieve what the OP wants (in Java).  Java 8 with default methods makes this even easier - but not everyone can jump on the bleeding edge yet :-).

Answer (score 1):

Given that's not allowed to implement multiples interfaces, you can consider the use of encapsulation. (example using java8+)

```
// Mappable.java
public interface Mappable<M> {
    M mapTo(M mappableEntity);
}

// TwoMappables.java
public interface TwoMappables {
    default Mappable<A> mapableA() {
         return new MappableA();
    }

    default Mappable<B> mapableB() {
         return new MappableB();
    }

    class MappableA implements Mappable<A> {}
    class MappableB implements Mappable<B> {}
}

// Something.java
public class Something implements TwoMappables {
    // ... business logic ...
    mapableA().mapTo(A);
    mapableB().mapTo(B);
}
```

Please check here for further info & more examples: [How to make a Java class that implements one interface with two generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298351/5535262).

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IMappable<S, T> {
    T MapFrom(S source);
}

// T - target
// S - source
```

If you want to map User to UserDTO and map User to UserViewModel, then you'll need two separate implementations. Don't pile up all this logic into a single class - it doesn't make sense to do that.

**Update to keep Joachim happy**

```
public interface ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination>
{
    TDestination Convert(TSource source);
}
```

But now we are in the Automapper realm (http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters)

Comment: I don't think `IMappable` is a good name for something that maps other things. `Mapper` (or `IMapper`, if you must ;-)) is probably more correct. (By the way: no, that was not my downvote).

Comment: I have taken what was in the question and prefixed with an I to highlight the fact it's an interface. I'm solving design problem as per question, as opposed to a naming problem.

Comment: sorry, but in my opinion one can not really "solve" a design problem and ignore naming. Design means understandable structures. Wrong naming is a problem to understanding.

Comment: Update should put your mind at rest ;-)

Comment: @CodeART If I understood your answer correctly it implies "MapFrom" (which should be lowercased ;-) creates the object. In my case it's just filling information on an already created object.

Comment: Naming convention of a method varies from team to team. There isn't a golden rule as to how the method should be named.